# How to export issues on Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, issue-tracking

Is there an option to export all issues / TODOS to csv or pdf file in GitLab?

Comment: You are right, your question should not belong in here.

Comment: Andrejs is probably right, it's off-topic. You can export to CVS if you are using enterprise edition 9.0 or later. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/issues/csv_export.html

Comment: I was able to export issues on gitlab.com CE and now the export button just disappeared. Did this feature got disabled on CE? Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about whether specific website functionality is available.

Comment: I created a system for access api of gitlab-ce and export issues. Is open source!
You can put your server name of gitlab, your access token and selected your group and the button for export to csv. Sample! https://gitlab-ce-export-to-csv.github.io
https://github.com/gitlab-ce-export-to-csv/gitlab-ce-export-to-csv.github.io

Answer (score 18):

As other users have commented, CSV export is built into paid versions of gitlab:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/issues/csv_export.html

However that does have issues - it emails the report to you and hence gitlab limit it to 20MB in size, and depending on the version of gitlab you're using some of the fields may not be present in the export.

Thankfully gitlab has a good API (including in the free version), so you can extract issues via the [issues API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/issues.html#list-issues) instead, and once you have that data it's very simple to output it in CSV format.

I wrote a very simple perl script that does this, it's available here and should work with free & paid versions of gitlab and also on gitlab.com:

https://gitlab.com/emobix/get-all-gitlab-issues-as-csv

Comment: As a side note, the API is available in the community edition as well.

Comment: Exporting issues to CSV has been moved to Gitlab Free in version 12.10 on Apr 22, 2020.

Comment: Export to CSV does not seem to include Comments - is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: @StevePitchers you'd need to update the script to call the notes API. It's not a lot of work but it's also not trivial.

Comment: But is there a way to export issues as separate Markdown files?

Answer (score 3):

You may export issues to CSV by reading the issue list RSS feed.

Click on the "Subscribe to RSS feed" button in GitLab issue list to get a link.

[image]

Then you may programmatically export issues.

I created a small script for this purpose, my snippet: https://gitlab.com/snippets/1868740